# Second connection to Bluetooth device fails in Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to establish a Bluetooth connection in Android 4.4 but the connect method of BluetoothSocket seems to be working strangely. My app can assume the device is already bonded, so I can connect via MAC address. The thing is that it connects perfectly and immediately the first time the device is bonded, but if I relaunch it, the connection isn't established and a timeout occurs. I do this inside a while loop until it connects, but it takes too long for a real solution or it doesn't work at all. Here's a sample of my code:

```
public class BluetoothManager{

    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;
    private BluetoothSocket socket;
    private OutputStream output;
    private InputStream input;

    public BluetoothManager() {
        /***************/
        /* Constructor */
        /***************/

        // lock = new Object();

        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    }

    public boolean turnOnBluetooth() {
        /**************************************/
        /* Turn on Bluetooth an notify result */
        /**************************************/

        // check if bluetooth is supported
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            return (false);
        } else {
            // enable Bluetooth if not enabled yet
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                bluetoothAdapter.enable();
            }
            while (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Log.i("Debug", "Waiting for bluetooth to turn on");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            return (true);
        }
    }

    public boolean turnOffBluetooth() {
        /***************************************/
        /* Turn off Bluetooth an notify result */
        /***************************************/

        // check if bluetooth is supported
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            return (false);
        } else {
            // disable Bluetooth if not enabled yet
            if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                bluetoothAdapter.disable();
            }
            while (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Log.i("Debug
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            return (true);
        }
    }

    public boolean configureBluetooth(String MACaddress) {
        /***********************************************************************/
        /* Configures to the specified bluetooth device and returns the result */
        /***********************************************************************/

        Log.i("Debug", "Connecting to Bluetooth Device");
        bluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MACaddress);

        return (true);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void createSocket() throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException{
        final UUID serialUUID = UUID
                .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

        socket = null;
        output = null;
        input = null;


         Method m = bluetoothDevice.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class });
         socket = (BluetoothSocket)m.invoke(bluetoothDevice, 1);
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void connect() throws IOException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        /************************************/
        /* Connects to the bluetooth device */
        /************************************/

        Log.i("Debug", "en connect");
        while (!socket.isConnected()) { // we try until the connection is established
            try {
                socket.connect();
                output = socket.getOutputStream();
                input = socket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i("Depuración", "Connection not established. Another run : "+e);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void terminateConnection() throws IOException {
        Log.i("Debug", "terminating connection");
        if(output!=null){
            Log.i("Debug", "output!=null - stop streaming");
            stopStreaming();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        if(input!=null){
            Log.i("Debug", "input!=null");
            input.close();
            input=null;
        }
        if(output!=null){
            Log.i("Depuración", "output!=null");
            output.close();
            output = null;
        }
        if(socket!=null){
            Log.i("Debug", "socket!=null");
            socket.close();
            socket=null;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        turnOffBluetooth();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        System.gc();
    }
```

If I call this methods from my MainActivity, it works, but only the first time the device is bonded. If I launch the app again I get an exception trying to connect to the device in:

```
socket.connect();
```

I suspect it has something to do with the way I terminate the connection, but I can't figure it out. Here's the sequential call of the methods:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bluetoothManager = new BluetoothManager();
        try {
            bluetoothManager.terminateConnection();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        bluetoothManager.turnOffBluetooth();
        bluetoothManager.turnOnBluetooth();

        boolean configured = false;
        while (!configured) {
            Log.i("Debug", "Configuration Attemp");
            configured = bluetoothManager.configureBluetooth(MACaddress);
        }

        Log.i("Debug", "Bluetooth Configured");

        try {
            bluetoothManager.createSocket();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i("Depuración", "Socket created");

        try {
            bluetoothManager.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i("Debug", "Connected!!!!");

protected void onPause() {
    Log.i("Debug", "On pause");

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        bluetoothManager.terminateConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bluetoothManager = null;
    System.gc();
    super.onPause();
};
```

I've been trying to solve this for days and I still can't find a reason.

Comment: Did you refer BluetoothChat sample application? If not, then please go through it.

Comment: Instead of waiting for 500msec try listening for action BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not a Pro on this, but it looks like you should call  `bluetoothManager.terminateConnection();` when app is closing, lets say `onDestroy`, but not `onCreate`; I also had problems to connect, if previous connection was not terminated correctly. just try add this method to your main activity:

```
  @Override
  public void onDestroy(){
    if (bluetoothManager != null){
        bluetoothManager.terminateConnection();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

hope that helps.

Comment: What exactly is your BluetoothManager? Can you give a doc reference or at least a parent package name?